# $\int_{C_N} \frac{dz}{z^2\sin(z)}$ complex integral, problem with residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> Let $C_n$ be the rectangle, positively oriented, which sides are in the lines $$x=\pm(N+\dfrac{1}{2})\pi~~~y=\pm(N+\dfrac{1}{2})\pi$$
>   with $N\in\mathbb{N}$. 
>   Prove that 
>   $$ \displaystyle\int_{C_N} \dfrac{dz}{z^2\sin(z)}=2\pi i\left[ \frac{1}{6}+2\sum_{n=0}^N \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^2\pi^2}\right]  $$

---

**what I did**

If $f(z)=\dfrac{1 }{z^2\sin(z)}$ then $f$ has a pole of order 3 in $z=0$ so the value of the integral is equal to $2\pi i (\text{sum of residues}) $ so, it  gives me the factor $\frac{1}{6}$. then every point $z=n\pi, ~~ n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\cdots,\pm N$ are simple poles. my question is:

**How i calculate the residues in those points**?

What am I missing? Am I doing it wrong?

$$z^2\sin(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{z^{2n+3}}{(2n+1)!} $$

Comment: the answer must depend on $N$ because $f(z)$ also has poles wherever $sin(z)=0$

Comment: $N$ is probably the upper limit in the sum, which is summing the residues from the poles at $z=\pm n\pi$

Comment: @WW1 yes, thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a [solution](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2GCdlcaMB9dTDZzb0NBY2hkYjRQSEEzWldqSkRoTFpLVUhr) in latex for this but is in spanish, this problems comes from Churchill: Complex Calculus with applications. hope it helps.

Comment: Sure friend, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The function 
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 \sin z} = \frac{1/z^2}{\sin z}
$$
has simple poles at $z = n\pi$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \neq 0$, so
$$
\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname*{Res}\limits} \Res_{z=n\pi} f(z) = \frac{1/z^2}{\cos z} \Big|_{z=n\pi} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2\pi^2}.
$$
In particular, the residue at $n\pi$ is equal to the residue at $-n\pi$, so it's enough to sum over the positive integers up to $N$ and multiply by $2$. This leaves us with the residue at $z=0$. Here
\begin{align}
f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2\sin z} &= \frac{1}{z^2 ( z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots )} \\
&=\frac{1}{z^3} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - \cdots} \\
&= \frac{1}{z^3} \left(1 + \left( \frac{z^2}{3!} - \frac{z^4}{5!} - \cdots \right) - \left( \frac{z^2}{3!} - \frac{z^4}{5!} - \cdots \right)^2 + \cdots \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{z^3} + \frac{1}{6z} + \text{terms of positive degree}
\end{align}
where the series expansion is valid near $z=0$ (we use the Maclaurin series for $\sin z$ and the geometric series, keeping track of terms of degree $3$ or less). Hence
$$
\Res_{z=0} f(z) = \frac16,
$$
which gives you the final term in the sum.

Comment: I'm curious about the downvote.